# date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un campo tipo datetime en mi tabla y deseo mostrarlo en la vista tipo date, para poder realizar búsquedas de fecha sin hora, solo y/m/d
intenté lo siguiente:

```
<td>{{date_format(($art->fecha), 'YYYY/m/d' )}}</td>
```

pero obviamente algo estoy haciendo mal, si me pudieran orientar por favor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El motivo del fallo ocurre por que el argumento que le pasas al método en cuestión es un *string*, pero en la propia [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php#refsect1-datetime.format-parameters) se indica que debe ser un **objeto DateTime**

En principio lo puedes resolver pasando ese string a:

- Una instancia de la clase Carbon, mediante el método `parse` añadido en la versión 1.3.0, sugiero revises [la doc. de **Carbon**](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

  ```
  {{date_format(now()->parse($art->fecha), 'Y/m/d' )}}
  ```
- O bien en una instancia de la clase [`\DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) de PHP

  ```
  {{date_format(new \DateTime($art->fecha), 'Y/m/d' )}}
  ```

Y deberías obtener la salida esperada.

- Ahora para tu caso en concreto, puedes establecer el formato por ejemplo desde el controlador del string en cuestión, como expongo en este ejemplo:

  ```
  $fechaInicial = "12/04/2000"; //aquí asignarías el valor en cuestión

  $fechaAntesFormato = now()->createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $fechaInicial);

  $fechaFinal = $fechaAntesFormato->format("Y/m/d");

  return $fechaFinal;
  ```

Donde agregamos el uso del método `createFromFormat` para tener con un formato específico en la instancia de Carbon el string pasado e igualmente debe darte la salida esperada.

Aquí comparto además [la lista de parámetros válidos para format](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `now()` aquí: `$fechaAntesFormato = now()->createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $fechaInicial);` cuando puedes crear la fecha en base a la cadena con algo como esto: **`$mDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('YYYY/m/d', $art->fecha);`** (aquí me he basado en los datos originales mostrados en la pregunta). Una vez creado el objeto se usa `format()` para mostrarlo. Ver el métdo [`createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php) de la clase `DateTime` para más detalles.

Comment: @A.Cedano cuando hago `now()->createFromFormat` obtengo una instancia de carbon con un formato específico, si bien es cierto lo que mencionas, como Carbon extiende de DateTime también lo puedo trabajar de esta manera